# C# Socket: what if sender sends more than received?

Tags: c#, sockets

Suppose the sender keeps sending and the receiver keeps receiving and there is **NO** feedback sent from receiver to sender that "I have received that message" or "I have received three messages so far".

Suppose the sender sends data much faster than the receiver can receive.

I suppose the underlying buffer will fill up, then the integer returned by the **Send** method will become zero, which tells the caller that "**Nothing has been sent**". When the caller sees this, it shall sleep a few seconds before calling **Send** again.

Am I right?

Comment: TCP? The receiving OS keeps sending feedback about available buffer space. Eventually the caller will fail to write into the OS buffer at their end. UDP? data will be lost.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy for your quick response!

Comment: As Jeremy Lakeman said: TCP/IP (streams) automatically handles flow control; UDP (datagrams) does not.  It's not really an issue with either "sockets" (in any platform/any language) or C# per se.  Here are detailed explanations: http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPReliabilityandFlowControlFeaturesandProtocolMod.htm

Comment: Probably also you have an undelete vote to your own, recently deleted meta post. 3 are needed to undelete and 5 to reopen.